# Is there a way to see the result of NIntegrate's symbolic preprocessing?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, symbolic

`NIntegrate` can do [a number of different types of symbolic preprocessing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#12996145) on the integrand before starting the numerical calculations, including changes of variables.

Is there a way to find out what sort of symbolic preprocessing is being done and what is the precise integrand `NIntegrate` is actually evaluating?  For example, is it possible to find out if it does any changes of variables, and if yes, exactly what changes it does?

---

Motivation: I'm trying to understand what goes wrong here: [Why do I get a different value when I change the order of integration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41454/12)  The question describes a simple oscillatory numerical integral in 2D.  `NIntegrate` gives different results depending on the order of integration variables, and no warnings.  One result is wrong.  Looking at the points sampled by `NIntegrate` it's clear that Mathematica does a different change of variables depending on the order of integration variables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This does not completely answer the question, but you can get some useful information from the undocumented option `IntegrationMonitor`. For example:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1}, IntegrationMonitor -> Print]
```

[image]

You can see (in the `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``) that the change of variables $\sqrt{x}\to x$ has been used to convert the integrand to $2 x \sin (x)$, which is then computed using the `ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule`.

Be aware that for complex integrands you will get a **lot** of output, so `Reap`/`Sow` might be better than `Print`.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008) are more details for [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008).