# How much time should one give Mathematica for an integral evaluation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Sometimes when I do integrals in Mathematica (M), it keeps thinking and thinking and I have no idea what is going on inside M. For how long should one wait or how does one know whether M has not got stuck in some loop or something? These integral may be algebraic or numerical ones. **Is there a rule of thumb** for how much time one should give M to evaluate an integral before aborting?

Comment: Have you seen `TimeConstrained`?

Comment: No I have not, but what I meant was that if there is a way to know whether one should wait some more or simply abort? I.e. if M is really working or just simply stuck.

Comment: It can be hard to tell, admittedly; hence my suggestion.

Comment: The numeric and analytic cases are very different.  `NIntegrate` might reasonably take a very long time just because the integrand evaluation takes a long time.  As to analytic `Integrate`, I cant say I've seen it take more than an hour or so and come back with a *useful* result.  If its important maybe let it chug away over night, but no longer than that..

Answer (score 19):

For what it's worth, you can monitor the progress of `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`.  I'm not sure how helpful the tools below are, but I feel it is probably worth mentioning them.

#### Integrate

**`` Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch ``**

If you set `` Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch `` to the magic number `10`, it will print its (major) steps in searching for the answer.  For instance:

```
Block[{Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch = 10},
 Integrate[Exp[-x]/Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, Infinity}]
 ]
```

Be prepared for lots of output in terms of internally named functions.  It's rather hard to understand what's going on, though not completely impossible.  For a computation that goes on for a long time, it would be a lot of stuff to wade through.

**Other debug printers**

Also, each submethod of `Integrate` seems to have its own debug-printing functions.  Here are some (I don't know them all).  Each has to be loaded, since most of the integration code is loaded as needed.  This can be done by calling `Integrate`.

```
Integrate[Exp[-x]/Sqrt[1 + x^3], x];
Integrate[Exp[-x]/Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, Infinity}];
Names["*Int*`*db*"]
(*
 {"Integrate`EllipticTrig`db", "Integrate`ImproperDump`dbgPrint", \
  "Integrate`AlgebraicFunctionDump`dbgPrintalg", \
  "Integrate`ConvolutionGGDump`dbgPrintcongg", \
  "Integrate`NLtheoremDump`dbgPrintDI", \
  "Integrate`Elliptic`dbgPrintEE", \
  "Integrate`EllipticTrig`dbgPrintEET", \
  "Integrate`ExponentialsDump`dbgPrintexp", \
  "Integrate`ImproperDump`dbgPrintII", \
  "Integrate`LogarithmDump`dbgPrintlog", \
  "Integrate`QuickLookUpDump`dbgPrintQT", \
  "Integrate`FindIntegrandDump`dbgPrintslatr", \
  "Integrate`TableDump`dbgPrintT", "Integrate`TableDumpExp`dbgPrintTE", \
  "Integrate`TableDumpSpec`dbgPrintTS", \
  "Integrate`TableDumpTrig`dbgPrintTT", "Integrate`EllipticTrig`db$"}
*)
```

They can be used like this

```
Block[{Integrate`QuickLookUpDump`dbgPrintQT = Print},
 Integrate[x Sin[x], x]
 ]
```

or this

```
Reap@Block[{Integrate`QuickLookUpDump`dbgPrintQT = Sow[{##}] &},
  Integrate[x Sin[x], x]
  ]
```

Again, probably of limited usefulness.

#### NIntegrate

I don't know of any debug-Print-like controls within `NIntegrate`, but you do have `EvaluationMonitor` and the undocumented `IntegrationMonitor`.

**`EvaluationMonitor`**

For `EvaluationMonitor`, perhaps the best use is to count the number of evaluations, which can be displayed dynamically in real time while the computation is ongoing.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] :=  (* N.B. designed to be particularly SLOW *)
  Interpolation[Table[{t, Sin[100 t]}, {t, 0, 1, 1./2^10}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x];
k = 0;
Dynamic[k]
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> k++, MaxRecursion -> 20]
(* k is 34279 at the end *)
```

One could also store the evaluation points.  I thought something like this would work, since dynamic updating is designed to have a low priority, but when the number of evaluation points gets large, thing slow down.  The kernel would actually **crash** at low settings of `UpdateInterval`. Bummer...and **beware**.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Interpolation[Table[{t, Sin[100 t]}, {t, 0, 1, 1./2^10}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x];

Clear[g];
k = 0;
pts = Sequence[];
g := Graphics[         (* Graphical monitor *)
   Dynamic@Refresh[
     Point[#[[;; ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/800]]] &@Level[pts, {-2}]], 
     TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1],
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True];
Dynamic@g

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> (pts = {pts, {{++k, x}}}), MaxRecursion -> 20]

g = Graphics[Point[Level[pts, {-2}]],  (* set g to be static *)
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True];
```

[image]

**`IntegrationMonitor`**

For `IntegrationMonitor` option (at least in the `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy), its setting should be a function, and the function seems to be passed a data structure like this:

```
{NIntegrate`IntegrationRegion[{{0}, {1}}, 
  Experimental`NumericalFunction[{x}, 1/Sqrt[x], "-NumericalFunctionData-"], {}, 
  NIntegrate`GeneralRule[{
    {0.007957319952578756`, 0.046910077030668074`, 0.12291663671457531`,
     0.2307653449471585`, 0.3601847934191085`, 0.5`, 0.6398152065808915`, 
     0.7692346550528415`, 0.8770833632854247`, 0.9530899229693319`, 0.9920426800474212`},
    {0.0212910183755409`, 0.057616658311237225`, 0.0934003982782463`, 0.12052016961432388`,
     0.13642490095627946`, 0.1414937089287456`, 0.13642490095627946`, 0.12052016961432388`,
     0.0934003982782463`, 0.057616658311237225`, 0.0212910183755409`},
    {0.0212910183755409`, -0.0608467842168579`, 0.0934003982782463`, -0.11879416563535941`, 
     0.13642490095627946`, -0.14295073551569884`, 0.13642490095627946`,
    -0.11879416563535941`, 0.0934003982782463`, -0.0608467842168579`, 0.0212910183755409`}}
  ]]}
```

The first argument is the subinterval being integrated.  One could monitor the progress with

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 IntegrationMonitor :> (Print[#[[1, 1]]] &)]
(*
  {{0},{1}}
  {{0},{0.5}}
  {{0},{0.25}}
  {{0},{0.125}}
*)
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 3 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.124005}. NIntegrate obtained 1.9779036090196027 `and 0.033906515833193304` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*  1.9779  *)
```

This may vary with the method strategy and/or rule.

#### Notes

I'm not sure where I heard of `debugSwitch`.  A search of the site turned up nothing (neither did Google).  I'm pretty sure it was mentioned in a comment on this site, or maybe by spekunking.  But you can see it in a `Trace`, e.g. `Trace[Integrate[x Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], TraceInternal -> True]`.  Lots of solvers have `*Print` methods built into them.  They can be found with `` Names["*`*Print"] ``, although, like `Integrate` the names might not show up until the corresponding module has been loaded;.  There are several kinds of `*Print` methods, but the debug ones often have `db`, `dbg`, `debug` or `Debug` preceding `Print` and start with a lower-case letter.  The output is not particularly user-friendly and I suspect they were not meant for end-users.

I discovered `IntegrationMonitor` via `Trace`: For example,

```
Trace[
 NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}],
 _NIntegrate`InitializeIntegrationStrategy,
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

Searching the site, I found it has been used once so far, by Simon Woods in his answer to [Is there a way to see the result of NIntegrate's symbolic preprocessing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41504/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-result-of-nintegrates-symbolic-preprocessing/41512#41512)

Comment: @LoveLearning You're welcome.

Comment: @LoveLearning perhaps you could consider editing the question title to something like "How to monitor Integrate and NIntegrate progress?". That way the answerable part is emphasized and the other one ("How long does it take?") is kept only in the inner text. The main purpose of the proposed change would be to insert useful keywords (monitor, integrate, progress) in the question title for future searchers

Answer (score 8):

There probably cannot be general answer for such a general question because the bigger integrand (other conditions being equal) the more time `Integrate` needs to handle it. But for basic tabular integrands there are some benchmarks made by Albert Rich, the developer of [Rubi - rule-based integrator](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/). On the linked page a table is given where the "**Timeout**" column means "the number of problems the system fails to integrate within a 25 second timelimit". From this table it is clear that *Mathematica* 9 on his computer (characteristics are absent but I'm quite sure it is an ordinary cheap computer, not a super-computer) cannot finish in 25 seconds evaluation of only 2% of the integrals from his test suite (which can be downloaded from the same page). So you can expect that *Mathematica* is able to take almost any standard indefinite integral within 25 seconds. If it fails then probably it is just unable to take it at all.

Also you can download his test suite and produce your own benchmarks.

Comment: Cool answer. So in short, one should use other software to numerically integrate? I used to use Matlab for that and liked it, but thought that I should learn that in Mathematica too. RUBI seems awesome btw.

Comment: @Love, not necessarily; note that `NIntegrate[]` supports a number of methods that can be tried if the default setting is not up to snuff. But more importantly, the nature of your integrand (and its accompanying singularities) will often demand the use of a non-default setting.

Comment: [this page](http://12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/index.htm)  has CPU time of problems used, for V 10.1. No time out is used in this one.

Comment: Cool interesting @Nasser