# How to show steps of Integrate[Exp[-(I*(s*t))]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*Sqrt[s]), {s, 0, Infinity}]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implementation-details

I am trying to use Wolfram Alpha in *Mathematica* 10.2 to show me the steps for calculating the integral in the title, i.e I have written the following command:

show steps of `Integrate[Exp[-(I*(s*t))]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*Sqrt[s]), {s, 0, Infinity}]`

in the Wolfram alpha command line, but it doesn't show me the steps, can anyone help me on how to make *Mathematica* show me the steps for calculating this integral?

Comment: *Mathematica* and more in general computer algebra systems do not carry out integration in the same way one would in basic calculus, so the steps would not be either recognizable or particularly useful. This topic has been discussed before: [Is there a way for me to get Mathematica show its steps?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82937/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-get-mathematica-show-its-steps)

Comment: See also [Get a "step-by-step" evaluation in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica)

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151) shows how, but I suspect the reason you're not seeing the step-by-step button is because *Mathematica* / W|A does not know how to break it down.  (Generally the steps are **not** the steps *Mathematica* takes.)  [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85489/4999) shows how to get an outline of the steps `Integrate` takes.

Comment: Step-by-step integrals in alpha only are currently available for integrands with elementary anti derivatives, and this one is not elementary (it's in terms of `Erf`): `In[1]:= Integrate[Exp[-(I*(s*t))]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*Sqrt[s]), s]

Out[1]= -(((-1)^(1/4) Erfi[(-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[s] Sqrt[t]])/(
 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t]))`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Wolfram|Alpha questions are out of scope for Mathematica.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rubi integration package](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) by Albert Rich, shows the steps, using its rules, for indefinite integration.

I've used this to show the steps for each of the over [51,000 integrals](http://12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/index.htm) in Albert's independent integration test suite.

Here is how you'd do the above for this example

After you load the package, then type

```
stepInt[Exp[-(I*(s*t))]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*Sqrt[s]), s]
```

It will now show that it used 3 rules to get to the final result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The [stepInt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.symbolic/gebD8OLfXfs) is thanks to Albert. Here it is. It will continue printing each step until it reaches the final result, or until it determines it can't solve it.

```
stepInt[u_, x_Symbol] := 
 Block[{ShowSteps = True}, FixedPoint[Function[Print[#];
    ReplaceAll[#, {Defer[Int] -> Int, Defer[Dist] -> Dist, 
      Defer[Subst] -> Subst}]], Int[u, x]];
  Null]
```